# Kiam okazos la deka Oficiala Aldono de la Akademio?

Tags: movado, akademia-vortaro

De tempo al tempo, la Akademio de Esperanto publikigas [Oficialan Aldonon](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oficialaj_aldonoj), liston de vortoj kiujn ĝi forte rekomendas. La Vikipedia artikolo montras ke la dato de publikiĝo de tiu listo ne estas perioda. Ekzemple estis nur 1 jaro inter la 4a kaj la 5a Oficiala Aldono, dum estis pli ol 30 jaroj inter la 8a kaj la 9a. Kiel eblas scii kiam okazos la venonta?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Kiel direktoro de la Sekcio pri Ĝenerala Vortaro de la Akademio de Esperanto, mi certe estas la persono, kiu plej bone povas respondi al ĉi tiu demando.

En la jaroj tuj post la fondo de la Lingva Komitato, oni relative rapide oficialigis multajn radikojn, ĉar oni volis rapide ŝtopi breĉojn en la oficiala radikaro. Intertempe, la oficiala radikaro ne plu havas multajn gravajn mankojn, tiel ke malpli urĝas rapide oficialigi multajn radikojn.

Nuntempe, la Akademio preferas ellabori siajn decidojn en tre singarda maniero, anstataŭ rapide fari decidojn pri multaj vortoj. Fakte, la ĉefa tasko, pri kiu la Akademia Sekcio pri Ĝenerala Vortaro nuntempe okupiĝas, estas difinado de radikoj, kiuj jam oficialiĝis en la 1a Oficiala Aldono, sed kiuj tiam estis oficialigitaj kun inter si malkoheraj nacilingvaj tradukoj (kaj sen Esperantaj difinoj, kiuj povus indiki, kiu signifo estis intencita). Do iusence ni balaas post niaj antaŭuloj, ĉar ili tro ***haste*** oficialigis, kaj tial ne sufiĉe zorgis pri la kohereco de la oficialaj tradukoj.

La ĵus uzita radiko *hast/* fakte estas la sola neoficiala radiko en ĉi tiu respondo. Kaj ĝuste pri ĝia oficialigindeco nuntempe okazas diskuto en la Sekcio pri Ĝenerala Vortaro, ĉar diskuto pri la radiko *urĝ/* el la 1a Oficiala Aldono kondukis nin al la demando, ĉu ni povus rekomendi *hastigi* por certa signifo de *urĝi*, kiun pluraj Akademianoj konsideras nerekomendinda. Povus okazi, ke ĝi estos oficialigita sendepende de samtempa oficialigo de multaj aliaj radikoj (kaj ankoraŭ ne klaras, ĉu tia oficialigo ricevus la numeron 10a, aŭ ĉu ĝi restus ekster la numerado).

Antaŭ la sekva samtempa oficialigo de multaj radikoj ĉiukoaze certe pasos almenaŭ kelkaj jaroj. Tio dependas interalie de tio, kiom longe ni ankoraŭ laboros pri difinado de radikoj el la 1a Oficiala Aldono, kaj kiom grandan kvanton da eble oficialigindaj radikoj ni poste alfrontos.

Answer (score 0):

Ĝi estis aprobita per voĉdono la 24-an de septembro 2023.

Comment: Kiam oni publikigos la 10OA-n? Mi ne trovis ĝin en la retejo de AdE.